# file.append fails to aggregate .rtf files

Tags: r, filesystems, rtf

I have used file.create and file.append successfully to aggregate multiple .txt files.  When I try it with .rtf files, however, I get a larger rtf file that only shows the contents of the first .rtf of many to be aggregated.

So I have 5 .rtf files, for example.  dirFiles is the list of names to be aggregated:

```
file.create(fileCollection_r)             
file.append(fileCollection_r,dirFiles_r)
```

Is this a bug, and I would I report it?
How can I aggregate multiple .rtf files?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not clear what `file.create()` resp. append is doing. You didn't tag for a specific programming language, so that part of your question is really unclear and you need to improve that.

Having said that: RTF files, are in the end, pure text files. They contain **formatting** information, such as

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1671\cocoasubrtf100
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
{\*\expandedcolortbl;;}
```

So, theoretically, you can just pull that text content from multiple RTF files, and put all of that into a single file.

Thus: simple use a file viewer, such as `less`, `cat`, or some windows/macos pendant, and A) check the *textual* content of your single RTF files and B) check out the *textual* content of the file that you created this way. That will tell you if the pure textual append did work.

But beyond that: it could very well be that the RTF format itself has certain limitations, that simply make it **not possible** to just append arbitrary RTF file content and end up with something that works as a correct RTF document.

Comment: I suspect, as you say, RTF files have a header that interfere with proper appending of files.  This is in R.  So I'm wondering if there is an R function that appends RTF files, so I don't have to do it.

Comment: Well, R is a data / mathematical language. Merging rtf files doesn't exactly sound like it fits that scope...